# Compile different .css files from common .scss template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sass

I have a Site model which looks like this

```
create_table "sites" do |t|
  t.name :name
  t.text :primary_colour, :default => "#a0a8af"
  t.text :secondary_colour, :default => "#91c500"
end
```

Using the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline I would like to dynamically use these site specific colours in my common site.css.scss file, but unfortunately I only know what the current site is at runtime based on the URL.

How can I use these colours in the CSS? Can I precompile one .css file for each Site from the common site.css.scss.erb file? Can I somehow render and cache it from a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it the easy way and output the styles on the page itself to override the global CSS
Having a controller serve the CSS wouldn't be bad either, just set the mime type and render a .scss.erb file, and use action caching.